# How do I go through values of a class

Tags: python, class, openweathermap

I'm having some trouble with the following:

A module for an API for `openweather` is returning the following type:

`class pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather`

It can return the following values:

```
{'1h': 1.34}
{}
```

How do I take the separate items (like `'1h'` and `1.34`)??

Answer (score 1):

{'1h': 1.34} is a python dictionary. In general you can iterate over its keys and values by the following loop:

```
for x,y in d.items():
    print(x,y)
```

where for ever key x, y is the correspondent value.

To get keys separately:

```
mykeys = d.keys()
```

To get values separately:

```
myvalues = d.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a python dictionary. To get the keys ('1h') in this case, you can do:

```
my_dict =  {'1h': 1.34}
keys = my_dict.keys()
```

To get the items:

```
values = my_dict.values()
```